# how we track JavaScript file is included or not by another website

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write affiliate program for one of my client. I wrote some JavaScript code to track some information on my client website. now problem is how i can track that JavaScript file is live or not on client server. If they remove then is that any tool that i can track the file is live or not.

Comment: You can find it in loaded files..Network tab..

Comment: but how i can track dynamically. means like using tag manager should i do

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tools for this task. Just get all the scripts then check whether or not the expected file exists.

```
if(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script')).some(script => script.src === yourExpectedURL)){
    alert('file found on the current page').
}
```